# Assigning ranks of elements relative to the other elements of a row in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

How to assign ranks of elements relative to the other elements of a row in a matrix?
For example, I'd like to convert:

```
A = [1 2 4 0; 
     2 3 1 8; 
     9 1 2 3];
```

into:

```
[1 2 4 3; 
 2 3 1 4; 
 4 1 2 3]
```

Comment: Is the first row in the example output correct?

Answer (score 3):

To rank the elements of each row you can use the second output of [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), twice:

```
A = [1 2 4 0; 2 3 1 8; 9 1 2 3];
[~, result] = sort(A,2);
[~, result] = sort(result, 2);
```

For your example, this gives

```
result =
     2     3     4     1
     2     3     1     4
     4     1     2     3
```